# Simple guide for installing Eclipse multi-user on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

Is there a simple guide available anywhere on how to install a recent version of Eclipse on Linux as a "normal" application?

The version in the Debian repositories, even for Debian 9, is a 3.X version of Eclipse, which must be very old, as they are now at V4.7.

The default method for the "eclipse.org" versions to install themselves is to put everything in the home directory, which is not a great approach for a system where the home directory is supposed to only contain user data (e.g. the whole home directory is backed up daily)

I can't believe that something so widely used does not have any good instructions for how to install it as a normal application would be - where all the application files are in a shared folder under /opt, and only user data is stored in the home folder.

I have found this thread, which may be promising:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1080525/

And a previous question seemed reasonably good, but on trying to follow it, the installer screens have changed, and everything about "bundle pools" became very confusing!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer. This is how I have been doing for a few years now.

- Download it from website and extract eclipse folder under /opt
- Change ownership of the folder to your user and make it readonly recursively.
- Create a desktop file to launch it as a regular user.
- You can make the folder writable once in a month to make sure latest updates are installed then make the folder readonly again.

Comment: So you just use the "package" version of Eclipse, rather than the installer? Their website claims that the installer is "easier and more efficient"

Comment: Yes, that's what I do but it should not make a difference if you use the installer. Once you update ownership and permissions of the eclipse directory, it should work fine. Take a look at "Scenario #2 - shared install" here:   https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR give up now

I found this when Googling for how to do a multi-user install on Linux Mint 20.

Although Eclipse [publish specific documentation on how to do a multi-user installation](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) this little correlation with the current reality.

I first tried installing the package version of Eclipse. That installed the flatpak package, not a native package. It turns out that flatpak has a bug (opened in 2017) whereby it creates a new image each time you run the binary - and at 1.2G that was eating my enterprise storage very quickly. Although the package installed from the command line use `apt` it did not add any record to the installed package list - so I couldn't uninstall it with `apt` (using `flatpak uninstall eclipse` seems to have worked).

I then downloaded the tarball eclipse.

This has a GUI installer which would not run via [x]sudo - so I had to subvert the usual security model on Mint/Ubuntu and make the root user a logon account.

I specified the install location as /usr/local/eclipse. The installer did its thing. Sadly it did not provision a menu entry for the program. Since it actually installs in a sub-directory of the target named with versioning information (/usr/local/eclipse/jee-2019/12/) I created a shell script in /usr/local/bin/ to point to the binary (so when I upgrade, I just need to change the shell script to point to the new location). I then created a .desktop entry to run the shell script and ran:

```
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor eclipse.desktop
```

I also copied the eclipse.desktop file to /etc/skel/Desktop and to /root/Desktop

From my root session, opening the .desktop file by double clicking, or running the shell script started eclipse.

Sadly, this did not create a start menu entry (it has worked for me with other applications).

Logging on a different user, copying the .desktop file to ~/Desktop and running it resulted in....
[image]

(Of course it would have been far too easy to display the failure reason in the dialog, or even put the path to the log file in a widget where I could copy and paste it)

Looking at /usr/local/eclipse/jee-2019/12//eclipse.ini, I find this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
--launcher.library
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.14.0.20191212-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

There is a whole catalog of issues here.

I replaced the relative path for `-startup` with an absolute one, copied `/root/.p2/pool` to `/usr/local/eclipse/pool` and updated the -startup and -showsplash entries in the file.

I got a whole new error message:

`!SESSION Fri Feb 19 11:11:27 GMT 2021 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2021-02-19 11:11:27.893
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.1.600.v20190814-1451.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2021-02-19 11:11:28.070
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
...`

I get exactly the same error after converting the Fedora 33 RPM to a .deb and installing that.

I'm going to go check the price of intellij licences.